# How to customize google timeline chart based on count of occurrences?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How to customize google timeline chart based on the count of occurrences from high to low? I have to customize timeline chart based on the count of occurrences. [code link](https://codepen.io/jangajack/pen/ENxPJW)

```
 dataTable.addRows([
            ['President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
            ['President', 'John Adams', new Date(1796, 2, 4), new Date(1802, 2, 4)],
            ['President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new 

Date(1809, 2, 4)],
            ['Vice President', 'John Adams', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
            ['Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
            ['Vice President', 'Aaron Burr', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1805, 2, 4)],
            ['Vice President', 'George Clinton', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'John Jay', new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 22)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1790, 2, 22), new Date(1793, 11, 31)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph', new Date(1794, 0, 2), new Date(1795, 7, 20)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', new Date(1795, 7, 20), new Date(1800, 4, 12)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'Charles Lee', new Date(1800, 4, 13), new Date(1800, 5, 5)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'John Marshall', new Date(1800, 5, 13), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'Levi Lincoln', new Date(1801, 2, 5), new Date(1801, 4, 1)],
            ['Secretary of State', 'James Madison', new Date(1801, 4, 2), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
          ]);

          chart.draw(dataTable);
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data) to find the number of occurrences

```
var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,  // data table
  [0],   // group by column(s)
  [{     // aggregation columns
    column: 0,
    type: 'number',
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
  }]
);
```

the result is another data table

you can then sort the data table descending by the `count` column

```
dataGroup.sort([{column: 1, desc: true}]);
```

this will give you the counts for each president

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['President', 'John Adams', new Date(1796, 2, 4), new Date(1802, 2, 4)],
    ['President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)],
    ['Vice President', 'John Adams', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Vice President', 'Aaron Burr', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1805, 2, 4)],
    ['Vice President', 'George Clinton', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'John Jay', new Date(1789, 8, 25), new Date(1790, 2, 22)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1790, 2, 22), new Date(1793, 11, 31)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'Edmund Randolph', new Date(1794, 0, 2), new Date(1795, 7, 20)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'Timothy Pickering', new Date(1795, 7, 20), new Date(1800, 4, 12)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'Charles Lee', new Date(1800, 4, 13), new Date(1800, 5, 5)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'John Marshall', new Date(1800, 5, 13), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'Levi Lincoln', new Date(1801, 2, 5), new Date(1801, 4, 1)],
    ['Secretary of State', 'James Madison', new Date(1801, 4, 2), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
  ]);

  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0],
    [{
      column: 2,
      type: 'date',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.min
    }, {
      column: 3,
      type: 'date',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.max
    }]
  );
  dataGroup.sort([{column: 1}]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataGroup);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of adding a table, can't we synchronize chart data with table data?

Comment: Thanks, can we visualization based on the count of values displayed in one row. Like someone was a president for 3 terms will be on top, then someone for 2 terms, then for 1 term.                                                                                  Values will be displayed in decreasing order of number of count.